# Error creating the user defined data type

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have recently installed Oracle Application Express 11g.

I am trying to create the below user defined data type.

```
create or replace type dept_type AS Object
 (
    dept_no DEPT.deptno%type,
    dept_name DEPT.DNAME%type,
    LOC DEPT.LOC%type
  )
```

In the definition above, DEPT is the table already exists in the current schema. 
When I am executing the above SQL command I am getting the below exception on the console.

```
Error at line 4: PLS-00201: identifier 'DEPT.DEPTNO' must be declared

2. (
3. dept_no DEPT.deptno%type,
4. dept_name DEPT.DNAME%type,
5. LOC DEPT.LOC%type
6. )
```

I don't understand why the above exception is coming? Is it something wrong with my definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object type is an **SQL** object. You can't use `<object>%type` in SQL, you can only use this type of construct in PL/SQL code.

For instance this will fail:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (x dual.dummy%type);
```

You need to specify the exact datatype, as if you were creating a table.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your answer.

Comment: If I want to know about other SQL object can you please provide useful link.

Comment: Sure, you could start with the [SQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8001.htm#BABHJHEB). There's also a complete [Object-Relational Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm).

Comment: Thanks vincent for all your help.